# Problematic suspend on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, suspend, power-management, systemd

On the same hardware suspend used to work without problems previously - worked just fine in 16.04 and worked without issues in the past with 18.04 as well! Some upgrade seems to have broken it!

```
Kernel version: 5.4.0-47-generic
systemd: 237
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep: s2idle [deep]
```

If I do `echo mem > /sys/power/state` the system goes to suspend correctly and wakes up without any huge issues (other than the normal nvidia-chrome noise)!

If however I try to suspend through xfce / normal power management or by `systemctl suspend` the system hangs completely (in a kernel panic way), I get no logs of it failing what-so-ever and I have to hard-reboot to get it back online!

Any ideas/suggestions?